# How do I use a relative path in XDocument.Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an XML file named PageData.xml in my App_Data folder. I want to populate an XDocument with this file using XDocument.Load.

If I supply the full physical path it works, i.e.:

```
XDocument vXDoc = XDocument.Load("/Work/Project/Web/100413 Dev/App_Data/PageData.xml");
```

...where "Work" is a folder on my C: drive.

If I try a relative path like this, though, I get a DirectoryNotFoundException:

```
XDocument vXDoc = XDocument.Load("AppData/PageData.xml");
```

"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\AppData\PageData.xml'."

This is obviously wrong, but there must be an easy way to set the correct relative path? What am I overlooking? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do it. You can use [Server.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28VS.90%29.aspx) to turn a virtual directory into a physical directory path:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/PageData.xml"));
```

Or you can use [Request.PhysicalApplicationPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx) as well, like so:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data\\PageData.xml");
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

In either case, the problem is that the current working directory of the worker process is usually *not* set to the application directory (this is because working directory is a process-wide property, and a single process can host multiple web sites). [More information is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx).

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response. Your first suggestion doesn't work for me "as is", but if I add a '~' to the path it works perfectly, i.e.:

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/PageData.xml"));

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems to be a IIS6 thing, adn I'm using IIS7.